# Is it legit to copy someon's elses contract code and change it slightly to be unique and has a green checkmark on Etherscan?

Tags: tokens

I would like to create a smart contract and tokens on Ethereum platform. Is it legit to copy someon's elses contract code and change it slightly to be unique and has a green checkmark on Etherscan?

thanks.

Comment: Yes definitely, you can use any smart contract and make changes or even make no changes at all. The same contract can be deployed multiple times. Just that your contract will have a unique address and the contract is separated from each other by ABI and their contract address

Comment: Thanks! Great, I don't see an option to make a question answered... could you please post it as an answer so I can check it and give you some points :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as the solution as this solves Op's question:

Yes definitely, you can use any smart contract and make changes or even make no changes at all. The same contract can be deployed multiple times. Just that your contract will have a unique address and the contract is separated from each other by ABI and their contact address.

Answer (score 1):

Technically an Ethereum contract will work regardless of where it came from. You can copy-paste source code, or you can copy compiled code.

Ethically and legally, if you're copying someone's code you need a license. Some projects already attach licenses that will allow anyone to copy the code. Sometimes this has restrictions or requirements, for example the requirement to credit the people who wrote the code. Some projects don't explicitly state a license, but they will grant you one if you ask them.